# Minimize browser window using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

Is there a Javascript or jQuery method to minimize the current browser window?

Comment: That would be pretty scary!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is no way to minimize the browser window within javascript.

There are ways to change the size of the window, but no true minimization (nice word)

Comment: Really nice word, cheers to that!

Answer (score 5):

No, there isn't. 
However, depending on what you're doing and which browsers you're targeting, you could play around with the blur and focus events of the window to achieve similar effect.

Comment: can you describe your method?

Answer (score 3):

If you use an extension, then you can minimize by `chrome.windows.update(window.id, { state: 'minimized' })`

Answer (score -10):

I hope this is what you are looking for:

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">

function Minimize()
{
window.innerWidth = 100;
window.innerHeight = 100;
window.screenX = screen.width;
window.screenY = screen.height;
alwaysLowered = true;
}

function Maximize()
{
window.innerWidth = screen.width;
window.innerHeight = screen.height;
window.screenX = 0;
window.screenY = 0;
alwaysLowered = false;
}
</SCRIPT>

<A HREF="javascript:onClick=Minimize()">Minimize</A>
<A HREF="javascript:onClick=Maximize()">Maximize</A>
```

Comment: When you state reference code, please consider adding the reference instead of appropriating the intellectual rights to yourself. This answer's code is literally taken from a nr.1 Google Search on "js to minimize windows", at http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/article.php/3471151/MinimizeMaximize-a-Browser-Window.htm

Comment: I'll plagiarize yet another section of the same page: "This is an effect I have been using for a short while on some other sites I've worked on, and I thought it might make a nice tutorial. I'm really sorry to say that at the time of this tutorial (7/28/00 - Kathie Lee's last day with Regis) it only works on Netscape Navigator 4.0 and above."  Netscape Navigator 4.0 is not a good target browser for your code.  This is a deprecated 13 year old "solution".

Comment: This doesn't even work in all the browsers. Very poor answer.