# javascript open new popup window but in minimized mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

HI I want a javascript code which open new popup window but in minimized mode

I use following code for that but its comes over in open mode

```js
let popup = window.open('', "s", "width=720;height=300;left=300;top=300;resizable=yes;toolbar=no;location=no;directories=no;status=no;menubar=no;scrollbars=yes;resizable=no;copyhistory=no").blur();
window.focus();
```

Please help...

I also use  window.blur(); but its not working also did lot of google for same but did not get solution.

Comment: heh I don't think its possible due to spawn invisible warriors :)

Comment: HI Thanks for your reply but It's possible this is called Pop under advertising  for reference you can watch this video ...https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xtba7pE36zM   but I could not understand how to make it possible

Comment: Ok so I think its not minimalized but hold active window still alive as active. So new opened window is under the active window. Look how set/hold active window still active.

Comment: Yes this will also help me..

Comment: This can be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34607780/open-new-window-or-tab-but-keep-focus-in-the-current

Comment: Not working also this example for tab I want same for popup window

Comment: Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/601832/4053389)

Comment: I check that already but how to do pop under you can see in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xtba7pE36zM,,, if some one did it off curse there is way...I need do it any how...please help

Comment: its done by using window.open().close();

Answer (score -2):

Thanks to every one take a look on it its been done by

window.open().close();

instead of window.blur();   or window.focus();

Comment: It just closes the popup, not minimizes it